# macOS Sierra caps-lock mapped as Esc has to be pressed twice

Tags: macos, keyboard

I've mapped my Caps Lock to be Escape:
 [image: screenshot]

Using a Microsoft Natural Keyboard with macOS Sierra.

Problem is I have to hit Caps-Lock twice for it to do anything. First hit does nothing.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out IntelliType got removed somehow during a recent upgrade. No idea how.

Once I re-installed it, keyboard is back to normal.

Similar issues with my MS mouse were solved as well by installing IntelliSense (the mouse's middle click stopped closing tabs in chrome and started doing task switching...).